# Relative words for "mid-"

Tags: word-request

It's allowed in English to prefix words with "mid-" when we are talking about middle of something: `mid-fall` (`mid-autumn`), `mid-1920s`, `mid-year`, `mid-week`, `mid-2016`.

Are there similar prefixes to refer *beginning* and *end* of something? What are actually the shortest (possibly informal) ways to say, for example, `the beginning of the year 2016` and `the end of the year 2016`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest ways that I can think of are

> start of 2016  *(3 words)*
>   *the beginning of the year 2016*
>
> year-end 2016  *(2 words)*
>   *the end of the year 2016*

For prefixes

> **neo**natal
>   *newly born*
>
> **Neo**lithic
>   *New Stone Age*
>
> **peri**mortem
>   *near death, but the context for "end" is given by "mortem"*
>   *peri- means around*

Comment: As I understand, I cannot shorten `the beginning of` and `the ending of` to some hyphened prefixes/suffixes: `beg-2016`, `2016-end`, can I?

Comment: @Sasha - You cannot use "beg-"; nobody would understand that.  "2016-end" is more understandable, although I would not say it's usual.

Comment: Prefixes and suffixes don't seem to be specific to "beginning" and "ending", it always involves some understanding of what you're trying to say, there are prefixes for "before"="pre","ante" (preholiday); "after"="post" (postholiday); "between"="intra","peri" (intraholiday)

Comment: @Sasha You might say as shorthand "start-2016", "end-2016" which would be understandable.

Comment: I understand about `pre`, `inter`, `semi`, `quasi`, etc. But I'm interested only about beginning and end, not others. It's good that I can say `start-2016` and `end-2016` (they line up with `mid-2016` much better than non-prefix variants).